# Unable to add Kotlin Android Extensions to my project

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

When i try to add kotlin-android-extensions via:

`apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'`

to my project Android Studio tells me *Plugin with 'kotlin-android-extensions* not found??

What is going wrong? I am Running Android Studio 3.0 Canary 8

Answer (score 47):

I think it's all about ordering,
make sure you have plugin orders like that

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'
```

Comment: Order actually matters in gradle?

Comment: Thank you very much @Jemo Mgebrishvili, I'd just like to put more attention to your answer, I spent many hours looking for this issue

Answer (score 13):

Android Studio 4.1

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
}
```

Answer (score 12):

Please also consider that you must be careful about `apply plugin:` orders:

So in order to apply `kotlin-android-extensions` you must first apply `kotlin-android`. Same as the following coode:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
```

Answer (score 3):

you are all done good but you have to add the plugin id to dependencies classpath in your gradle file like this

```
buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.60'
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
  }
}
```

you always have to add that and after doing this, add the following in your gradle(app) file

```
compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
```

and you are all done

Answer (score 1):

In your gradle app:

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
```

and in your activity:

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.height_dialog_ft.*
```

Then you can use any id in your activity directly by their id name which your
have mentioned in your .xml file

Answer (score -1):

Ooops. I forgot to add the kotlin gradle plugin as mentioned here:
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-gradle.html#plugin-and-versions